# Can you do a Select * FROM CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to do a `CASE WHEN` statement in the `FROM` clause in a SQL Server query?

For example

```
SELECT SaleDate 
FROM 
   CASE WHEN GETDATE() <= '01-Apr-2014' THEN tbl1 ELSE tbl2 END
```

Comment: not in that way... you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: No. You can only use `CASE` where an expression is allowed, and the `FROM` parameter doesn't allow expressions. Use a `UNION`.

Comment: Or another option is IF/THEN if there is only one or a few cases.

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvote swarm.  I haven't had review privileges for very long, but your question looks really reasonable compared to most other questions I edit or comment on.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a UNION:

```
SELECT SaleDate
FROM tbl1
WHERE GETDATE() <= '01-Apr-2014'
UNION ALL
SELECT SaleDate
FROM tbl2
WHERE GETDATE() > '01-Apr-2014'
```

Comment: That's going to do the same as SELECT SaleDate from tbl1 and tbl2. He wants table 1 for one date and table 2 for other dates.

Comment: The `WHERE` clauses in each subquery cause it to use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: aaaaah very interesting... I have never seen it done that way before. +1 for cool alternative :)

Comment: Note that this introduces a DISTINCT on each table, where the intention expressed in the original question doesn't seem to require that. So you should mention UNION ALL.

Answer (score 2):

Try using IF/THEN

```
If getdate() <= '4/1/2014'
BEGIN
SELECT SaleDate FROM tbl1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT SaleDate from tbl2
END
```

Answer (score -5):

No, you can't. And that would have been evident if you had bothered to try it. You would have seen the following error if you had tried it in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
```

For more info regarding the `FROM` clause of `SELECT` queries, see the MSDN documentation – [FROM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) [SQL Server 2008].

I'm marking this as community wiki because this question does not indicate that the asker performed even cursory research before posting it.

Comment: The OP no doubt did try it (hence the reason he's asking the question) and so he's asking if there's an alternative way to code it so it will work.